# QML TextArea onEditingFinished On Enter

Tags: qt, qml, user-experience

The QML `TextArea` inherits `onEditingFinished` From `TextEdit` where it is triggered on losing focus or an enter/return press. (assuming no input validation)

However one cannot trigger onEditingFinished from a `TextArea` with `Enter` unlike for `TextEdit` as it is captured for a line break.

Additionally in a window with a single field it can be a unintuitive to remove focus from the `TextArea` as background and most other Controls don't accept focus so the user has to click off the window or clicking the menu bar.

How can I improve the user experience for triggering actions once they have edited a multiline string input field? Is linebreaks inputted with `Ctrl+Enter`, with editing completion on `Enter` an option, and if so how would this be implemented?

Here is the example QML of this scenario:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640; height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Column {
        TextArea {
            implicitHeight: 200
            placeholderText: qsTr("Enter description")
            onEditingFinished: console.log("Editing complete")
        }
        Label {text: qsTr("Label")}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answers by Jarman (https://stackoverflow.com/a/69723941/1581658) and Farshid616 (https://stackoverflow.com/a/69724074/1581658) I came up with this

```
    TextArea {
        implicitHeight: 200
        placeholderText: qsTr("Enter description")
        onEditingFinished: console.log("Editing complete")
        
        Keys.onReturnPressed: {
            if(event.modifiers & Qt.ControlModifier) {
                insert(cursorPosition, "\n")
            }
            else {
                editingFinished()
            }
        }
    }
```

This specifically allows for a newline to be inserted at the current cursor when `Ctrl+Enter` is pressed, and for `editingFinished` to be called when a non-modified `Enter` is pressed

Comment: An example is also given in Qt documents here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-keyevent.html#modifiers-prop

Answer (score 1):

You can override the Return key press event and handle it however you want. If you want to use the Ctrl+Return, check the `modifiers` property in the event.

```
        TextArea {
            implicitHeight: 200
            placeholderText: qsTr("Enter description")
            onEditingFinished: console.log("Editing complete")
            
            Keys.onReturnPressed: {
                if (event.modifiers & Qt.ControlModifier) {
                    // Ctrl+Return
                    editingFinished();
                }
                else {
                    // Ignore other cases
                    event.accepted = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Or if you want to use the Return key without pressing Ctrl, then you can simply do this:

```
        TextArea {
            implicitHeight: 200
            placeholderText: qsTr("Enter description")
            onEditingFinished: console.log("Editing complete")
            
            Keys.onReturnPressed: {
                editingFinished();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I wanted a newline inserted on ctrl+return and other cases to call editingFinished, but this was a good basis, thank you. USed this to generate https://stackoverflow.com/a/69739186/1581658.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by handling the simple `ReturnPressed` and `ctrl+ReturnPressed` or `Shift+ReturnPressed` event by yourself.

In the code below I've used `Shift+ReturnPressed` for new line:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640; height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Column {
        TextArea {
            id: text_area
            implicitHeight: 200
            placeholderText: qsTr("Enter description")
            Keys.onReturnPressed: {
                if(Qt.ShiftModifier)
                    console.log("Editing complete")
                else {
                    text += '\n'
                    text_area.cursorPosition = text_area.length
                }
            }

        }
        Label {text: qsTr("Label")}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Not quite right, Qt.SHift modifer needs to be event.modifier & Qt.ShiftModifier (otherwise its always true!) and `text+= '\n'` adds a newline at the end and moves the cursor there, rather than inplace which was my desire, but I've used elements of your answer to generate https://stackoverflow.com/a/69739186/1581658